# Alternatives for automated CLI based Bluemix logins

Tags: authentication, automation, command-line-interface, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a shellscript based automation which uses cf cli (cf login) that uses Bluemix userid and password credentials. There are scenarios which involves several login attempts that happens during any point of time. One alternative approach i can see is reusing the bearer token generated once till it expires.

But I would like to see if there is any other approach the automation can be performed (such as using cf login -sso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I am aware of. When you get a new token from UAA, you also get a refresh token that can be used to renew the authentication token as many times as you like, perhaps rather than automating the CLI you should consider using the cloud controller API directly.